# How globally access the sql db from any viewcontroller

Tags: c#, ios, sqlite, xamarin

```
public class MedicineTransation{
[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
public int   Id { get; set; }
public string name {get;set;}
public int age {get;set;}
public string grade {get;set;}
}               

// StudentViewController
//Add student Record to student database.  
btn_AddRecord.TouchUpInside += ((object sender, EventArgs e) => { 

    string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    var db = new SQLiteConnection (System.IO.Path.Combine (folder, "student.db"));
    db.CreateTable<MedicineTransation>();
    var student = new Student { 

    name = studentName;
    age = studentage;
    grade = studentGrade;

    };
  db.Insert (student);

)};

//DetailedViewController
//Delete student Record to student database.  
   btn_DeleteRecord.TouchUpInside += ((object sender, EventArgs e) => { 

//  db.Insert (student); Insert Record into database.
//  db.Delete (student); Delete Record from database.

}
```

Want to access same db from another viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the repository pattern.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx

Alternatively (if that pattern is overkill), then you could create a model-class and let it manage itself through static methods or through a separate singleton.